# How "else" works in "1 line if" in C?

Tags: c, if-statement

I searched it up but I haven't found the answer to this, so I saw a piece of code as follows,

```
int a=0, b=1, c=0;
if (a)
if (b && c) puts ("yes");
else puts ("no");
```

I know that we may not use {} if the statement is only 1 line like `if (true) //something;`, so I assumed that `else` belonged to `if (a)` but when I run the code, `no` doesn't show up, at first I thought it's the same as

```
if (a) if (b && c) puts ("yes");
else puts ("no");
```

or,

```
if (a)
    if (b && c) puts ("yes");
else puts ("no");
```

But instead, it is

```
if (a)
{
    if (b && c) puts ("yes");
    else puts ("no");
}
```

Why that `else` is paired with the inner `if` instead of the outer `if`?

Comment: "Why did the language standard make the design decision that it made?" is not on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Interesting question for historical perspective point of view. Eager to see some more wiki answer on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this C11 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), **§6.8.4.1**, paragraph #3:

> 3 An **`else`** is associated with the lexically nearest preceding **`if`** that
> is allowed by the syntax.

In your case, the "nearest preceding if" statement is `if (b && c) puts ("yes");`.

Comment: Well, that makes sense. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

> Why that else is paired with the inner `if` instead of the outer `if`?

That's how it works, `else` gets paired with the closest `if`. It helps if you use correct indenting, either by hand or automatically by your IDE:

```
if (a)
    if (b && c) 
        puts ("yes");
    else 
        puts ("no");
```

Comment: So, even without a {} scope, it counted as if it in the same scope?